# Calculating the maximal time to access consecutive values in a DRAM in page mode

Tags: caching, memory, ram

From a 16MB DRAM, I have to calculate the maximum time it can take to read 8300 consecutive values. Here are the specifications that I have:

-the DRAM is structured as a table of 4096 x 4096 cell.
-it has a time cycle (Tc) of 65 ns.
-in page mode it has a time cycle (Tpm) of only 45 ns.

I thought it was simply done by calculating the number of cells in the DRAM and then calculating the percentage that 8300 represents from the total (4096 x 4096) and then taking that same percentage and multiplying it to the time access. Unfortunately it did not give me the right answer... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

There are many variables into account (e.g., Using open- or close-page mode, number of ranks), thus is memory dependent. In order for you to have a better understanding and re-state your question, please read this paper, which helped me to understand RAM better.

Power and Performance Trade-Offs in Contemporary DRAM System Designs for Multicore Processors

You can search for it in Google Scholar.

Thanks.